# Google Sheets auto move to next cell

Tags: google-sheets, formatting

I have an ID format checker that has a row of cells that can only have one specific kind of character in each cell, and then all characters are compiled in order into another cell to create the correct ID#. If an incorrect character is entered, it highlights the cell yellow to indicate it's incorrect. I want to be able to type a character into the first cell and it automatically tab over to the next cell. So let's say I type the number "3" into cell A2. Instead of having to press tab or the right arrow key, I want it to automatically make the next cell to the right the active cell. So if I type "G" into cell A2, the next time I type a character it goes into B2, and then next time I type a character it goes into C3, so on and so forth.

Any suggestions?

Here's a copy of the sheet I'm using. 
https://docs.google.com/spreadsheets/d/1mWxDIXsuKuxBziTkoUdufRxp_wyO035ENfltTTwetIs/edit?usp=sharing

Comment: Welcome. Please add a brief description of your search/research efforts as is suggested in [ask].

Answer (score 2):

This is highly impossible to jump from an active cell into a neighboring active cell without the medium (keyboard/mouse). The script just wouldn't know when you wish to jump because the state of the active cell is technically empty (even if you already typed in something) to the point when the active cell gets inactivated/out of the focus.

For such task, you will need 3rd-party script/macro which will mimic the action of pressing right arrow key at specific intervals (like every 5 seconds). Check out **[AutoHotKey](https://www.autohotkey.com/)**.

Comment: @user213235 Add-ons and AHK are both great ideas. Note AHK can also add a key-press after each of your key-presses. You could set it up where you hit a rarely used key to enter your "ID Entry" mode, and then after every character you type, AHK tabs to the next cell. Just be forewarned that setting it up is not trivial.

Comment: There are ways to do this in Excel, but I wasn't sure about in Sheets. And thanks for the suggestions, but it's a work computer and they won't install AutoHotKey on it for me: I tried a while back for an unrelated task and they said they won't. (╯°д°）╯︵ (\ . 0 .)\

Comment: why not run portable version on your stick?

Answer (score 1):

Having the opposite problem in SHEETS -- every time i type in a cell to edit a formula, when i hit ENTER it automatically goes into EDIT mode on the cell below it... and it is driving me insane!  How can I disable this functionality?!

Answer (score 0):

Echoing the other current answer, that behaviour exactly as described, is impossible.

I think you could get close to your requirements by having entry take place in just one cell. Then a formula like [MID](https://support.google.com/docs/answer/3094129) would pull each character out into your existing separate cells. They would then in turn be individual evaluated and flagged. Such an arrangement still could never be 'live' for each character *as you type them*, but it still achieves rapid entry and per-character validation.

Comment: That sounds like it could work well, I'll try that out. Thanks!